# Can a Modal Sheet have a Navigation Bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am presenting a modal sheet from a navigation bar button in my code:

```
struct MainPage : View {

    @State var isModalSheetShown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            [...]
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
            Button(action: { self.isModalSheetShown = true }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isModalSheetShown, content: {
            VStack {
                [...]
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                Button(action: { ... }) {
                    Text("Done")
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

But the Navigation Bar does not appear in the modal sheet as you can see below.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, how do you put a navigation bar on a modal sheet?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to wrap your modal view in a `NavigationView` like this

```
@State var isModalSheetShown: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Main")
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add",
                                         action: { self.isModalSheetShown = true }))
    .sheet(isPresented: $isModalSheetShown) {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Modal")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done",
                                                 action: {}))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I missed the NavigationView wrap. Thank you :)

Comment: perfect answer, @lulugaga. Can this NavigationView (that's modally presented) then push another controller onto its stack?

Comment: @PaulBruneau Yes, you can navigate further within the modal.

Comment: Hi @LuLuGaGa the done button does not click. Any reason why please?

Answer (score 3):

Modal view must be wrapped in `NavigationView` but the above solution using `.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done", action: {}))` is not working for me. What worked for me is, in the modal view I have to add a navigationButton and also to show the navigation bar I have to use the `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)`. So this is part of my ModalView code:

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            header
            infoBody
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    }
```